# RegEx for matching operation sequences

Tags: regex

I have a numbers operation like this:

```
-2-28*95+874-1545*-5+36
```

I need to extract operands, not implied in a multiplication operation with a regex:

```
-2
+874
+36
```

I tried things like that without success:

```
[\+,-]\d+(?=\+|-|$)
```

This regex matches `-5`, too, and

```
(?(?=\d+)[\+,-]|^)\d+(?=\+|-|$)
```

matches nothing.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What environment are you implementing this in?

Comment: Try `(?<!\*)[-+]\d*\.?\d+(?![*\d])`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What's this part for? `\.?\d+`?

Comment: @vintnes That would allow numbers which may contain decimals to be matched as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\*)[-+]\d*\.?\d+(?![*\d])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sWmmTP/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\*)` - (a negative lookbehind making sure the current position is) not immediately preced with a `*` char
- `[-+]` - `-` or `+`
- `\d*` - 0 or more digits
- `\.?` - an optional `.` char
- `\d+` - 1+ digits
- `(?![*\d])` - not immediately followed with a `*` or digit char.

See the regex graph:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much @WiktorStribiżew ! It's exactly what I was looking for ! It's works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/6kYrYH/1/) might help you to capture your undesired pattern in one group <kbd>()</kbd>, then it would leave your desired output:

```
(((-|\+|)\d+\*(-|\+|)\d+))
```

[image]

You can also use other language specific functions such as <kbd>(*SKIP)(*FAIL)</kbd> or <kbd>(*SKIP)(*F)</kbd> and get [the desired output](https://regex101.com/r/RkALfS/1):

```
((((-|\+|)\d+\*(-|\+|)\d+))(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|([s\S]))
```

[image]

You can also [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) your expression, if you wish, and remove unnecessary groups that you may not need.

Answer (score 1):

Another option could be to match what you don't want and capture in a group what you want to keep. Your values are then in the first capturing group:

```
[+-]?\d+(?:\*[+-]?\d+)+|([+-]?\d+)
```

Explanation

- `[+-]?\d+` Optional + or - followed by 1+ digits
- `(?:\*[+-]?\d+)+` Repeat the previous pattern 1+ times with an `*` prepended
- `|` Or
- `([+-]?\d+)` Capture in group 1 matching an optional + or - and 1+ digits

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TtCw8F/1)